# Error while building/deploying project simple-project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 clang 64bit) When executing step "qmake"

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, osx-yosemite

I have a mac os x `Yosemite` and I already have `xcode` installed. I downloaded qt 5, but when I try to run a sample project file on qt creator, at build step, this error shows us. I mean this is the compile output:

```
Error while building/deploying project simple-project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 clang 64bit)
```

When executing step "qmake"

please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post more information build log, etc.

Comment: what do you mean please?

Comment: This Errros is certainly not the only output you have. It must be preceded by logs.